# Extend or override a type field

Tags: typescript, generics

I need a type declaration that grants `value` field to have type `string` and all other fields are unchanged. I thought it was simple and wrote

```
type WithValue<T> = T & { value: string; }
```

Unfortunately in some cases I need `T` to be `any`. And that causes a problem - `WithValue<any>` becomes just an `any`. **How can I override a property of `any` type?**

---

Consider following [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20WithValue%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20%7B%20value%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f%3CT%20extends%20object%3E(x%3A%20T)%3A%20WithValue%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B...x%20as%20any%2C%20value%3A%20%22%22%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20x%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20y%20%3D%20f(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20y%20is%20any%0D%0Ay.value%20%3D%201%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20no%20error):

```
type WithValue<T> = T & { value: string; }

function f<T extends object>(x: T): WithValue<T> {
  return {...x as any, value: ""};
}

declare var x: any;

var y = f(x); // y is any
y.value = 1;  // no error
```

I want the last line to be an error because of assigning `number` instead of the `string`.

---

I've also tried [to omit](//stackoverflow.com/a/48216010/4928642) a field, but that caused [another problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20WithValue%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%26%20%7B%20value%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f%3CT%20extends%20object%3E(x%3A%20T)%3A%20WithValue%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B...x%20as%20any%2C%20value%3A%20%22%22%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20x%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20y%20%3D%20f(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20y%20is%20any%0D%0Ay.value%20%3D%201%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Diff%3CT%20extends%20string%2C%20U%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20(%7B%5BP%20in%20T%5D%3A%20P%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BP%20in%20U%5D%3A%20never%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20never%20%7D)%5BT%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Diff%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20z%3A%20WithValue%3COmit%3Cany%2C%20'value'%3E%3E%3B%0D%0Az.value%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0Az.value%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%20-%20Correct%0D%0Az.aghj%20%3D%200%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%20-%20I%20don't%20want%20this%20error%0D%0A):

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>;

declare var z: WithValue<Omit<any, 'value'>>;
z.value = "";
z.value = 1; // Error - Correct
z.aghj = 0;  // Error - I don't want this error
```

Comment: @Behrooz, any field except `value` to be `any`, but the `value` to be `string`. Also I want to see `value` in editor autocomplete list.

Comment: I'm using command `ts-node with.ts` and I get the error you expect: `with.ts:9
var y = f(x); // y is any`. What version of Typescript are you using?

Comment: @banan3'14, what error do you get? I don't expect any error in line you quoted.

Comment: ```
var y = f(x); // y is any
          ^
ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../with.ts:9:11)
```
Versions:
```
ts-node v5.0.1
node v8.10.0
typescript v2.7.2
```

Comment: @banan3'14, that's because you are running a code with `declare var` for var that doesn't exist. I need compile-time error at `y.value = 1;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about defining your type a little differently:

```
type WithValue<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & { value: string };
```

Then, using that, it seems to meet your criteria:

```
declare const x: WithValue<any>;
declare const y: WithValue<{a?: number}>

x.value.charAt(0); // Okay, since x.value has type string.
x.asdf.whatever; // Okay, since x.asdf has type any.

x.value = 1; // Error: Type number not assignable to type string.

y.value.charAt(0) // Okay, since y.value has type string;
y.a // Inferred to have type number | undefined (since it's optional)

y.asdf.whatever // Error: asdf does not exist on type...
```

Comment: Great! And even seems simple :)